# Help with complicated table

Tags: tables, excel2latex

I'm trying to replicate complicated table (scheme) from  Excel:

[image]

Cells with numbers (1, 2, ...) should be more or less squared. Lines forming right angle around center table are thicker than ordinary borders (not shown here).

I can make every table separately, but have no idea how to combine them together (with some small spaces in horizontal and vertical). Tried with excel2latex macro from ctan, but with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

As asked in comments, here are separate tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{c|l|r|}
    \cline{2-3} 
    \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some long text here}} & qwerty 1 & 1 \\[1.5ex]
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 2 & 2 \\[1.5ex]
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 3 & 3 \\[1.5ex]
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 4 & 4 \\[1.5ex]
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 5 & 5 \\[1.5ex]
    \cline{2-3}
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
    \hline
    4 & text \\
    \hline
    3 & text text \\
    \hline
    2 & text text text \\
    \hline
    1 & text \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc abc} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{long text here 2} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**

I ask this question to draw the attention of advanced users and packges' developers to the fact that people need an easy and robust way to make such complex "visual" tables. Complexity of creating tables makes people away from using LaTeX.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I edited question and added simple codes for separate tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

The rules of each sub-table are drawn by a command `\Block` (with the key `hvlines`) inserted in top-left cell of the sub-table.

The thick rule forming right angle is drawn with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` after the construction of the tabular (using PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the rows, columns and cells of the array).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{w{r}{8mm}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{clRw{c}{4mm}RRRRRcRl}[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
\Block{5-1}{\rotate some long text here}
& \Block[hvlines]{5-2}{}
  qwerty 1 & 1 & & \Block[hvlines]{5-5}{}
                   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & \Block[hvlines]{4-2}{}
                                         4 & text \\
& qwerty 2 & 2 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 3 & text text \\
& qwerty 3 & 3 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 2 & text text text \\
& qwerty 4 & 4 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 1 & text \\
& qwerty 5 & 5 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\\
&          &   & & \Block[hvlines]{2-5}{}
                   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & \Block[C,draw]{2-2}{centered text }\\
\RowStyle{\rotate}
&          &   & & abc & abc abc & abc & abc abc & abc abc abc \\  
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [thick] (1-|4.5) |- (6.5-|10) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

---

**Answer to the question in the comment**

I have non easy solution. I have changed the columns `w{r}{8mm}` in columns `p[r]{8mm}` because, in the columns `p`, it's possible to change the horizontal alignement with `\RowStyle{\centering}`. However, that creates a problem for the rotatede elements which are now wrapped at 8 mm (maybe I should change that in `nicematrix`). That's why I have use `\makebox`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{p[r]{8mm}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{clRw{c}{4mm}RRRRRcRl}[cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
\Block{5-1}{\rotate some long text here}
& \Block[hvlines]{5-2}{}
  qwerty 1 & 1 & & \Block[hvlines]{5-5}{}
                   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & \Block[hvlines]{4-2}{}
                                         4 & text \\
& qwerty 2 & 2 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 3 & text text \\
& qwerty 3 & 3 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 2 & text text text \\
& qwerty 4 & 4 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & 1 & text \\
& qwerty 5 & 5 & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\\
\RowStyle{\rotate\centering}
&          &   & & \Block[hvlines]{2-5}{}
                   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & & \Block[C,draw]{2-2}{centered text }\\
\noalign{\vskip 11mm}
\RowStyle{\rotate\centering}
&          &   & & \makebox[18mm][r]{abc} & \makebox[18mm][r]{abc abc} & \makebox[18mm][r]{abc} & \makebox[18mm][r]{abc abc} & \makebox[18mm][r]{abc abc abc} \\  
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [thick] (1-|4.5) |- (6.5-|10) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: very nice solution! I thought also about using `tikz` to arrange individual tables placed in nodes (like Roland's suggestion). The main difficulty is that I don't know how to set fixed width and height of a cell (say, cells with numbers) so that these sizes would be the same for all sub-tables, and then build other cells. In your solution this is done automatically -- all cells are of the same table, this is probably the only way.

Comment: may I ask one small sub-question?  I would like the bottom sub-table (with `abc` ...) looks the same as the left one (with `qwerty 1` ...) just rotated, i.e. `abc` are centered and bottom and numbers are rotated, centerd and up. I added `\RowStyle{\rotate}` before row with numbers, bu how to align those cells?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion to make just one table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf,justification   = justified,
    singlelinecheck = true}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck = false}
\usepackage{makecell} %<- EDIT 

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}   
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{This is a Table}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccl}
        \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some long text here}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{quwerty 1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{text} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{quwerty 2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{text text} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{quwerty 3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{text text text} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{quwerty 4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{text} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{quwerty 5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        &
        &
        \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{6-10}
        &
        &
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\ \cline{5-10}
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\ \cline{6-10} \cline{12-13} 
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{centered cell}} \\ \cline{6-10}
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \cline{6-10}
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead[l]{some long text \\ more text}} & <- EDIT
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \cline{12-13} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, but why column with "5" is not of the same width as other numbers 1, 2, 3, 4? "Corner" should be thicker and close to center table.

Comment: @AIx this is due to the long text. You can fix this by making a new line with `\usepackage{makecell}` see Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

If you want to have the tables seperated like you have given them in your MWE. You could also just insert them into a node and arrange them in a TIKZ picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table1) {%
  \begin{tabular}{c|l|r|}
    \cline{2-3} 
    \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some long text here}} & qwerty 1 & 1 \\
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 2 & 2 \\
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 3 & 3 \\
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 4 & 4 \\
    \cline {2-3}
    & qwerty 5 & 5 \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}};

\node[right of =table1, xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2pt] (table2) {%
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}};

\node[right of =table2, xshift=2.5cm,yshift=8.6pt] (table3) {%
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
        \hline
        4 & text \\
        \hline
        3 & text text \\
        \hline
        2 & text text text \\
        \hline
        1 & text \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}};

\node[above of =table2, yshift=-4.5cm] (table4) {%
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{abc abc abc} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{long text here 2} \\
\end{tabular}};

\draw[thick](1.75,1.5) -- (1.75,-1.8);
\draw[thick](1.75,-1.8) -- (5.25,-1.8);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks much better! It would be even better if one can make width of cells in `(table 4)` the same as in `(table 2)`., and rows height in `(table 1)` is slightly different from those in `(table 2)`.  Anyway (+1)!

Comment: Probably using `tikz` is a right way for such "visually constructed" complex tables, but the problem is that separate tables have slightly different cells' sizes.